# How to check newer than or equal to a date on access SQL

Tags: sql, ms-access-2007

Currently I have two tables, using Access 2007

TimeSheet(empID, TimeSheet, hours)
and
Rates(empID,Rate,PromotionDate)

How do I select the correct billing rates of employee based on their date of promotion?
For example, I have

```
Rates(001,10,#01/01/2013#)

Rates(001,15,#01/05/2013#)

Rates(002,10,#01/01/2013#)
```

and

```
Timesheet(001,#02/01/2013#,5)

Timesheet(001,#02/05/2013#,5)

Timesheet(002,#02/01/2013#,7)
```

In this case, I want to show that if empID 001 submited a time sheet at 02/01/2013 it would be billed with $10/hr
, but his timesheets starting at May 1st would be billed with $15/hr

My query right now is

```
SELECT t.empID , t.timesheet, r.hours , 
    (SELECT rate FROM rate WHERE t.timeSheet >= r.promotionDate) AS RateBilled 
FROM rate AS r , timesheet AS t
WHERE r.empid = t.empid
```

When ran, it shows a message of  “At most one record can be returned by this subquery”

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Edit:

I have some strange output using the sql

```
SELECT t.empID, t.timesheet, r.rate AS RateBilled
FROM Rates AS r, timesheet AS t
WHERE r.empid=t.empid And t.timeSheet>=r.promotionDate
GROUP BY t.empID, t.timesheet, r.rate, r.promotionDate
HAVING r.promotionDate=MAX(r.promotionDate);
```

[image: results]

as you can see the output table ratebilled for empID 1 is switching back and forth from 10 to 15, even though past May 01, it should all be using 15 ,

any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Umm won't the select subquery potentially return multiple values where only one should be returned?

Comment: @vegomatix hi there, hoping you can revisit this as the outputs were not as I expected.

Comment: Remove the promotionDate from the group by expression, it's telling it to put it in a separate slot.

Comment: @vogomatix hi again, when i take out the promotionDate from the group by expression, it prompts me saying "You tried to execute a query that does not include the specific expressions 'r.promotionDate = Max(r.promotiondate)' as part of an aggregate function. I think this is an issue of Access to include every entry in the Group by.

Comment: I don't think you need it in the groupby but may need the values in the select as a fudge. I'm at work at the moment but if I have a few moments later on I'll look into it

Comment: @vogomatix While playing around, I took out the HAVING r.promotionDate = MAX(r.promotiondate) and the results were the same as above. but this time i could run the query without including promotiondate in the GROUP BY , so I wonder if it's necessary then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The select subquery you have setup potentially returns multiple values where only one should be returned. Consider the case where there may be two promotions and a recent timesheet, then the select will return two values because on both occasions the timesheet is newer than the promotion.

Try using the following as your subquery:

```
SELECT TOP 1 rate FROM rate 
WHERE t.timeSheet >= r.promotionDate
ORDER BY r.promotionDate DESC
```

N.B. I don't think the above is terribly efficient. Instead try something like

```
SELECT t.empID , t.timesheet, r.hours , r.rate AS RateBilled
FROM rate AS r , timesheet AS t
WHERE r.empid = t.empid AND t.timeSheet >= r.promotionDate
GROUP BY t.empID, t.timesheet
HAVING r.promotionDate = MAX( r.promotionDate);
```